# Evaluating $\int _0 ^1 x^k(\ln x)^m dx$ for integer $k$ and $m$

Tags: integration

Find a formula for $\displaystyle \int _0 ^1 x^k(\ln x)^m dx$ that works for all positive integers $k$ and $m$. Use integration by parts $m$ times with $k$ fixed.

Comment: Have you done as told? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Could you please use $\LaTeX$ and a more descriptive title?

Comment: @Amzoti, I don't think your title accurately reflects the question.  Perhaps it should be something like "Evaluating $\int_0^1 x^k(\ln x)^m\,dx$ for integer $k$ and $m$".

Comment: @AntonioVargas: noted and updated! Regards

Comment: do you need to prove it or just find the formula?

Comment: yes I have done as told. I have set u= to lnx and du=to x^k. @DanZimm I need to just find the formula

Comment: @sam See my answer, guess it will help.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a start, use the change of variables $\ln(x)=-t$

$$ \displaystyle \int _0 ^1 x^k(\ln x)^m dx =\left( -1 \right) ^{m}\int _{0}^{\infty }\! {t}^{m}{{\rm e}^{-t \left( k+1\right) }}{dt}.$$

Now, you need another change of variables to relate the last integral to [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). I let you do it. Here is the final answer

$$ \left( -1 \right)^{m}\frac{ \Gamma(m+1) }{ (k+1)^{m+1} }=\left( -1 \right)^{m}\frac{ m! }{ (k+1)^{m+1} } . $$

**Added:** The other change of variables you need is $ (k+1)t=u $. Use it and compare with the gamma function.

Comment: what is the gamma function?

Comment: It is the generalization of factorial. $n! =\Gamma(n+1).$

Comment: Is their a way it could be done using integration by parts?

Comment: This method is easier.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I don't understand why anyone downvoted this solution.  I gave it +1.

Comment: @EricNaslund: Me either. That's why downvoting an answer without leaving a comment is misleading. I have been experiencing this on other correct answers. Anyways, thanks for your comment and upvoting.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal It seems to be $(-1)^{m+1}$ no ? Because we have $dx=-e^{—t}dt$.

Comment: @FreeX: It is correct. Have you worked out? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes, yesterday (the upvote is mine). It works perfectly well and very slick!

Comment: @FreeX: Good job. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 4):

Integrating by parts works out nicely:

Denote $$\varphi(k,m)=\int_0^1x^m(-\log x)^kdx$$

Note we **need** the minus on the $\log$, since it is **negative** over $[0,1]$!

Now take $$u=(-\log x)^k$$ $$dv=x^m$$ We get $$u'=-k(-\log x)^{k-1}\frac{1}{x}$$ $$v=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}$$

Thus IVP says

$$\varphi(k,m)=\left.(-\log x)^k\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}\right|_0^1+\frac{k}{m+1}\int_0^1(-\log x)^{k-1}\frac{x^{m+1}}{x}dx$$

This gives a nice recurrence, after noting both limits on the first term on the right hand side vanish:

$$\varphi(k,m)= \frac{k}{m+1}\int_0^1(-\log x)^{k-1}{x^{m}}dx$$

that is $$\varphi(k,m)=\frac{k}{m+1}\varphi(k-1,m)$$

But then $$\varphi(k,m)=\frac{k!}{(m+1)^{k}}\varphi(0,m)$$

Thus, all we need to is to know what $$\varphi(0,m)=\int_0^1x^m dx$$ is. But you can do that, yes?

Comment: I seem to have swapped $k$ and $m$. Feel free to edit the question to match the OPs usage of $k$ and $m$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different approach using exponential generating series. Notice that $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{m}}{m!}\left(\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}\left(\log x\right)^{m}dx\right)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{m}}{m!}\left(\log x\right)^{m}\right)dx$$ $$=\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+z}dx=\frac{1}{z+k+1},$$ and the right hand side has the expansion

$$\frac{1}{k+1}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{k+1}}=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{\left(k+1\right)^{j}}z^{j}.$$ Comparing coefficients, we find that $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}\left(\log x\right)^{m}dx=\frac{m!(-1)^{m}}{(k+1)^{m+1}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering the function $f(a)=\int_0^1x^adx=\frac{1}{a+1}$
now doing differentiation under integral sign of $f(a)$ wrt $a$, $m$ times
we have $f^{m}(a)=\int_0^1x^a(lnx)^mdx=\frac{(-1)^mm!}{(a+1)^{m+1}}$
now put $a=k$ we get $f^{m}(k)=\int_0^1x^k(lnx)^mdx=\frac{(-1)^mm!}{(k+1)^{m+1}}$

Comment: @AnivMazumber You can format $\ln x$ like this: \ln x. You might also consider putting your Latex in double dollar signs ('\$$ $$') to make the expressions bigger.