# Integral $I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^n-1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Hi I am trying to obtain a closed form for$$
I_n=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^n-1}dx, \quad n\geq 1.
$$
This integral is quite nice and generates many other known closed form results such as 
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1} dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8}, \quad \int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x-1} dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.
$$
In these cases I use residue methods, but am unsure how to generalize as in this case of $I_n$.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have

$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^n-1}dx=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^{nk}\ln x dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(nk+1)^2}$$

and for $n=1$ and $n=2$ the two sums are known.

Comment: This is very nice, Thanks so simply!  However, how do you justify switching the order of summation and integration here? I am interested in a mathematical proof which involves uniform convergence as well as solves the integral.  Thanks

Comment: We can use the theorem of integration term by term. *(I don't know what we call it in English)*

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for the solution

Comment: The last series it shouldn't be $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(nk+1)}$ ?

Comment: @FreeX No then the summer isn't convergent

Comment: @Integrals How can I calculate the last integral so ? (I tried integration by parts)

Comment: Yes you should integrate by parts@FreeX

Comment: @FreeX http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347815/evaluating-int-0-1-xk-ln-xm-dx-for-integer-k-and-m

Comment: @FreeX http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319921/use-integration-by-parts-to-prove-that-int-xn-lnx-dx-fracxn1n1

Comment: @Integrals Thank you!

Comment: Well done, Sami!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: technically, you need more to justify the interchange of summation and integration in an infinite summation. Term by term integration is fine for a finite sum, but you need something more, say Tonelli's Theorem or Fubini's Theorem for an infinite sum.

Comment: @robjohn Yes of course we need to justify the interchange of $\int$ and $\sum$ for a rigorous proof and as you said the Fubini's theorem is applied here since
 $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1\left|x^{nk}\ln x\right| dx<\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

(*Edited for rigour, credit for this goes to RandomVariable*).
$$I(\alpha)=-\int_0^b\frac{x^{\alpha}dx}{1-x^n}$$
$$I(\alpha)=-\left(\frac{b^{\alpha+n+1}}{ \alpha+n+1}+\frac{b^{\alpha+2n+1}}{ \alpha+2n+1}+\cdots\right)$$
Now, as $I'(\alpha)=\int_0^b\frac{\log(x) x^{\alpha}dx}{x^n-1}$, or rather, $J(\alpha)= \lim_{b \to 1}I'(\alpha)$ is something the value of which we want to find,
$$I'(\alpha)=-\log(b)\left(\frac{b^{\alpha+n+1}}{ \alpha+n+1}+\frac{b^{\alpha+2n+1}}{ \alpha+2n+1}+\cdots\right)+\left(\frac{b^{\alpha+n+1}}{( \alpha+n+1)^2}+\frac{b^{\alpha+2n+1}}{( \alpha+2n+1)^2}+\cdots\right)$$
So 
$$J(\alpha)=\lim_{b \to 1}I'(\alpha)=\left(\frac{1}{( \alpha+n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{( \alpha+2n+1)^2}+\cdots\right).$$
Then set $\alpha=0$ and we have accordance with the other answer:
$$J(1)=\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\cdots\right).$$

Comment: How is $x^\alpha$ related to $\ln x$

Comment: It looks like your series for $I(\alpha)$ is divergent.  If the integral does not exist how do you justify your equality?

Comment: The problem is that the integral diverges.  But there must be some way to justify this approach.

Comment: @Integrals $\frac{d}{d \alpha}I(\alpha)= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x) x^\alpha}{x^n-1}dx$.

Comment: I don't know how to justify playing with divergent integrals.

Comment: @Alyosha Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps integrate from $0$ to $b$. And then after differentiation, let $b$ go to $1$ from the left.

Comment: @RandomVariable Is there a rigorous way one could justify that that would make the integral converge (I'm really bad with this, despite trying to learn some analysis)?

Comment: The integral converges if the upper limit is less than $1$.  So I think you have to do what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @RandomVariable Oh, and only take the limit *after* differentiating?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Now you're not dealing with a divergent integral and a divergent series. Complete rigor would involve justifying bringing the limit inside of the infinite sum at the end.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$$
\Psi\pars{s + 1} + \gamma = \int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{s} \over 1 - t}
\quad\imp\quad
\Psi'\pars{1 \over n} = -\int_{0}^{1}{t^{1/n - 1}\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
$$

> With $\ds{t = x^{n}}$:
>   $$
> \Psi'\pars{1 \over n}=
> -\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{x^{n}}^{1/n - 1}\ln\pars{x^{n}} \over 1 - x^{n}}\,nx^{n - 1}
> \,\dd x=n^{2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{n}- 1}\,\dd x
> $$

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{n}- 1}\,\dd x
= {1 \over n^{2}}\,\Psi'\pars{1 \over n}}
$$
Note that $\ds{\Psi'\pars{1} = {\pi^{2} \over 6}}$ and
$\ds{\Psi'\pars{\half} = {\pi^{2} \over 2}}$.

> Some details are given in my [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/778088/85343).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{x^n-1}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{1-e^{-nu}}e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^\infty u(e^{-u}+e^{-(n+1)u}+e^{-(2n+1)u}+\dots)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=1+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\frac1{(2n+1)^2}+\dots\\
&=\frac1{n^2}\left(\frac1{(0+1/n)^2}+\frac1{(1+1/n)^2}+\frac1{(2+1/n)^2}+\dots\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac1{n^2}\psi^{\,\prime}\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{align}
$$
The order of integration and summation can be interchanged using [Tonelli's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) since everything is positive in the last integral.