# Solving an integral with parameter: $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln(1+a\cos x)}{\cos x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have this integral with parameter:

$$I(a) =\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln(1+a\cos x)}{\cos x}dx, 0<a<1 $$

Tried to use the differentation under the integral sign:

$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \frac{1}{a\cos x+1}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{a\cos x+1} = \frac{2\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{(-1 + a) \tan(x/2)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}} + C$$

I think that something goes wrong on this step. If I substitute ${a}$ into $\sqrt{a^2-1}$, the result is negative.

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: how can the result of your final integral depend on $x$?

Comment: You have the right idea; I think you just made a mistake integrating $\int \frac{dx}{a \cos(x) + 1}$

Comment: Actually, your work so far is completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work so far is completely fine; you just forgot to apply the *definite* integral.
Note that $\tanh(x/i) = \tan(x)/i$, so that $\tanh^{-1}(x/i) = \tan^{-1}(x)/i$.

We now have
$$
\frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \left. 
\frac{2\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{(-1 + a) \tan(x/2)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}
\right|_{x=0}^{x = \pi/2} = 
\frac{2\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{a-1}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}=\\
\frac{2\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{a-1}{i\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right)}{i\sqrt{1-a^2}} = 
\frac{2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a-1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right)}{i^2\sqrt{1-a^2}} = \\
-\frac{2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a-1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}
$$
And clearly, $I|_{a = 0} = 0$.  From there, integrate with substitution $u = \sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}$.

Comment: is the next integration so obvious? furthermore i think the sign of your squareroots is somehow of ...at least it is not obvious to a beginner how to make sense out of $\sqrt{a^2-1}$ for $0<a<1$

Comment: see my improved comment

Comment: You're right, it's not obvious

Comment: to tackle the integration w.r.t to $a$, try $\sqrt{1-a}/\sqrt{1+a}=q$ the result is very pleasing

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks a lot! Got it

Answer (score 0):

Let’s use Feynman’s Technique of Integration by defining
$$
I(a):=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln (1+a \cos x)}{\cos x} d x
$$

where $0\leq a \leq 1.$
Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
I^{\prime}(a)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+a \cos x} d x
$$
Letting $t=\tan \dfrac{x}{2}$, then $$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) &=2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{d t}{1+a+(1-a) t^{2}} \\
&=\frac{2}{1-a} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{d t}{t^{2}+(\sqrt{1+a})^{2}} \\
&=\frac{2}{1-a} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(t \sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\right)\right]_{0}^{1}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
I(a) &=2 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\right) d a \\
&\stackrel{a\mapsto\cos \theta}{=} -2 \int \frac{1}{\sin \theta} \tan ^{-1} \sqrt{\tan ^{2} \frac{\theta}{2}} \sin \theta d \theta \\
&=-\int \theta d \theta\\ &=-\frac{\left(\cos ^{-1} a\right)^{2}}{2}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Taking limits $0$ to $a$, we get the final result. $$
\begin{aligned}
I(a) &=\int_{0}^{a} I^{\prime}(y) d y =\left[-\frac{\left(\cos ^{-1} y\right)^{2}}{2}\right]_{0}^{a} =\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}-\frac{\left(\cos ^{-1} a\right)^{2}}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$